# Test for Proportion

Tags: r

Trying to calculate proportion for number of pairs of values. Why when used prop.test for one pairs or for several (pairwise.prop.test) i get a difference results?

If i run only for the first pairs i get: P-Value= 0.08181

```
prop.test(c(73,68),c(86,93),alternative ="two.sided")
##
##   2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction
##
## data:  c(73, 68) out of c(86, 93)
## X-squared = 3.0286, df = 1, p-value = 0.08181
## alternative hypothesis: two.sided
## 95 percent confidence interval:
##  -0.01122346  0.24653229
## sample estimates:
##    prop 1    prop 2
## 0.8488372 0.7311828
```

And when i run with more than 1 pairs i get diff. P-Value

```
smokers  <- c( 73, 68, 98, 70 )
patients <- c( 86, 93, 136, 182 )
pairwise.prop.test(smokers, patients)
##
##   Pairwise comparisons using Pairwise comparison of proportions
##
## data:  smokers out of patients
##
##   1       2       3
## 2 0.16    -       -
## 3 0.12    0.98    -
## 4 1.8e-11 4.4e-07 2.9e-08
##
## P value adjustment method: holm
```

What i do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I am no expert on proportion tests, but your question puzzles me.  What perspective are you coming from that indicates to you that adding data will not change the properties of your data and the subsequent calculations of critical statistics?

Comment: Notice the last line of output: `P value adjustment method: holm` now go do some research on that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Removing the "Holm" method from the pairwise.prop.test will return the same results, which adjusts p-values -- similarly to "Bonferroni". Note, the latter rounds to 3 digits.

```
prop.test(c(73,68),c(86,93), alternative ="two.sided")
smokers  <- c( 73, 68, 98, 70 )
patients <- c( 86, 93, 136, 182 )
pairwise.prop.test(smokers, patients, p.adjust.method = "none")
```